# Something with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Already for 15 minutes I can not understand

```
if(send == true){
$.getScript('index.php?get_names_from_ajax=true', function(data){
$('#firstnames').remove();
$('#lastnames').remove();
$('#content').prepand('<div class="block" id="firstnames">'+firstnames+'</div>');
$('#firstnames').after('<div class="block" id="lastnames">'+lastnames+'</div>');
send = false;
});
alert(send);
}
```

getScript works fine, but callback gives no results.

**EDIT**

As i said, all callback is off, nothing removes or adds, just no moving, like there is no callback.

Comment: which is not working in callback?

Comment: Where `firstnames` and  `lastnames` variables defined in the script? If they are not defined then this script is most likely throwing runtime exception.

Comment: all callback. No remove, no add, no alert for debugging

Comment: firstnames and lastnames are the div id's in html

Comment: Have you tried writing to the console the value of data : console.log(data); Can you expand on the question (as what is firstname and lastnames), also the callback usually takes 3 arguments: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr), see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: @MikeSav - If you aren't going to use the `textStatus` and `jqxhr` variables, you can just leave them out of your callback function. I usually only care about the `data` parameter.

Comment: @NoNameZ Do you have a syntax error somewhere? Have you checked or your JavaScript console for error messages? What is `send`? Have you verified that the value is, in fact, `true` right before your `if` statement?

Comment: Please post the index.php?get_names_from_ajax=true script, and use an error callback as well to see whether there are loading errors.

Comment: Thanks to @Bergi, the error was in json_encode which as now i understand supports only ascii chars...

Answer (score 2):

I think `firstnames` and `lastnames` should be `data.firstnames` and `data.lastnames`, if they are not defined in script before.

```
$.getScript('index.php?get_names_from_ajax=true', function(data){
  $('#firstnames, #lastnames').remove();
  $('#content').prepand('<div class="block" id="firstnames">'+data.firstnames+'</div>');
  $('#firstnames').after('<div class="block" id="lastnames">'+data.lastnames+'</div>');
   send = false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the method .prepand() is a typo. I suppose you're trying to use .prepend()

Look here for reference: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/